# Using MySQL without any procedures or functions

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement

Is it possible to use any sort of logic in MySQL without using any procedures? My web hosting does not let me create any procedures so I'm looking for a workaround.

The type of thing I want to do is only add an item to a table if it doesn't already exist. Or add a column to a table if it's not already there. There are some operations that can be done such as `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` and so on, but some operations I require do not have such luxuries :(

I realised late on that my lovely procs won't work and so I tried writing IF/ELSE logic as top-level queries, but for MySQL, IF ELSE blocks only seem to work inside functions/procs and not at the global scope.

Any workarounds greatfully received - I've already asked the hosting to grant me privileges to create procedures but no reply as yet...

Comment: just checking but i assume if you can't create procedures you can't create functions either?

Comment: Nope no functions, but I *can* access INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Comment: Please provide an example of something you're trying to implement. You can do a lot with keys and SQL. Is there a reason you can't do this in your application?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you don't have access to the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` either. You can possibly find solutions but it would be better, in my oninion, to:

**Change your hosting provider. Seriously.** Pay more - if needed - for a MySQL instance that you can configure to your needs. You only have a crippled DBMS if you are not allowed to create procedures and functions.

---

Posible workarounds for the specific task: You want to add a column if it doesn't exist.

1) Just `ALTER TABLE` and add the column. If it already exists, you'll get an error. You can catch that error, in your application.

2) (If you have no access to the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`) maintain a version of the schema, for your database.

Comment: I decided to go with your #2 which is to maintain a proper version of the DB, read the version at the application start and if it's different run my migration scripts from the current version number to the new version. More work now means less work for my future self :)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that I can think of would be to use an additional language with SQL.  For example, you can run a query for a specific record, and based on the response that you get, you can conditionally run an INSERT statement.

For inserting a table if it doesn't exist, try using the SHOW TABLES statement and testing whether or not a name exists in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html). and [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

The following will insert a new row, but only if there is no existing row with `id=10`. (This assumes that `id` is defined as a unique or primary key).

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table (id, col1, col2) values (10, "abc", "def");
```

The following will insert a new row, but if there is an existing row with `id=10` (again, assuming id is unique or primary), the existing row will be updated to hold the new values, instead of inserting a new row.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, col1, col2) values (10, "abc", "def")
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1=VALUES(col1), col2=VALUES(col2)
```

Also, `CREATE TABLE` supports the [`IF NOT EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) modifier.  So you can do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table ...
```

There are many other similar options and modifiers available in MySQL.  Check the docs for more.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I created a big script to create or update the database schema, to make it easier to deploy database changes from my local machine to the server.
My script was doing a lot of "if table 'abc' exists and it doesn't have a FK constraint called 'blah'" then create an FK constraint called 'blah' on table 'abc'... and so on.

I now realise it's not actually necessary to check whether a table has a certain column or constraint etc, because I can just maintain a schema-versioning system, and query the DB schema-version when my app starts, or when I navigate to a certain page.

e.g. let's say I want to add a new column to a table. It works like this:

- Add a new migration script to the app code, containing the SQL required to add the column to the existing table
- Increment the app's schema-version by 1
- On app startup, the app queries the DB for the DB's schema-version
- If DB schema-version < app schema-version, execute the SQL migration scripts between the two schema-versions, and then update the DB schema-version to be the same as the app

e.g. if the DB's schema-version is 5 and the app version is 8, the app will apply migration scripts 5-6, 6-7 and 7-8 to the DB. These can just be run without having to check anything on the DB side.

The app is therefore solely responsible for updating the DB schema and there's no need for me to ever have to execute schema change scripts on the local or remote DB.

I think it's a better system than the one I was trying to implement for my question.